# Showing set of of monic polynomials with repeated roots is an algebraic subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

**Problem:** Prove that the set $M$ of monic polynomials with repeated roots is an algebraic subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$. (throughout we work over an algebraically closed field $k$)

**Attempt:** I'm a bit confused here. Let's say I have a monic polynomial $f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots a_0.$ This can be seen as a point in $\mathbb{A}^n$, by taking the coefficients $(a_{n-1}, \ldots a_0) \in \mathbb{A}^n$ which uniquely determine the polynomial.

How can I prove the stated claim? I know that to every monic polynomial $f$, I can associate its discriminant $D(f)$, which will tell me if $f$ has repeated roots if $D(f) = 0$.

Help is appreciated.

Can I then just say that $M$ is the zero set of the discriminant of every monic polynomial? In what ring does the discriminant live?

I need to find an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ in $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, such that $M$ is the zero set of this ideal.

Comment: Don't you want an ideal in $k[a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}]$?

Comment: Not every polynomial with 0 discriminant has repeated roots. That is, for example $(x^2 + 1)^2$ has multiple roots in $\mathbb{C}$, but not in $\mathbb{R}$. If you can factorize the polynomial, the discriminant is equal to the product of the differences of the roots. Eg the discriminant of $(x-a)(x-b)$ is $(a-b)^2$ . The discriminat of  $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ is  $(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2$. The discriminant of a polynomial $p$ of fixed degree can itself be written as a multinomial formula of its coefficients (the determinant of the Sylverter matrix of $p$ and $p'$).

Comment: So, if you can solve for those particular issues (polynomial is factorize as a product of degree 1 monomials), there are no 0 divisors, etc, then the 0 set of the discriminant coincides with the set of coefficients of polynomials of repeated roots. The set itself is algebraic.

Comment: I'm assuming we are working over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Well, then it's simply a matter of using the two formulas of the discriminant. The root formula proves the zero-set of disc is the set of monic polynomials with repeated roots, and the determinant of the Sylvester matrix of coefficients formula proves it is algebraic.

Comment: A good book on the discriminant (and the methods of algebraic geometry in general) is "Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry" by Saugata Basu, Richard Pollack and Marie-Françoise Roy

Comment: Is the discriminant a polynomial in $k[a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}]$?

Comment: @user3257842, I don't understand your comment: "the determinant of the Sylvester matrix of coefficients proves it is algebraic." Can you explain? I know what the Sylvester matrix is of two monic polynomials is. But how does it prove the set of monic polynomials is algebraic exactly?

Comment: the discriminant of a polynmial $p$ is equal to the determinant of the Sylvester matrix of $p$ and $p'$, that is, $p$ and its derivative. So it is a multinomial algebraic function in the coefficients of $p$. It is a polynomial in  $k[a_0,a_1,…,a_{n−1}].$

Answer (score 1):

As was talked about in the comments:

The set of monic polynomials with repeated roots is the vanishing set of $\Delta$ where
$$ \Delta = \prod_{i < j} (r_i - r_j)^2 = (-1)^{n \choose 2} \det \operatorname{Syl}(p,p')$$

where $r_1,\dots,r_n$ are the roots and $\operatorname{Syl}(p,p')$ is the the [Sylvester Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix) of $p$ and $p'$.

The entries of $\operatorname{Syl}(p,p')$ are the coefficients of $p$ and of $p'$ and so the determinant gives you a polynomial in the coefficients of $p$.